# Как поставить псевдоэлемент по центру

Tags: html, css

как поставить по центру два псевдоэлемент по центру черной картинки
https://jsfiddle.net/wn6s5pqe/16/

```
      <div class="programs-page__body">
        <div class="item-programs-page__video video-item-programs">
          <div class="video-item-programs__play"></div>
          <div class="video-item-programs__item" poster="">
            <img src="https://www.meme-arsenal.com/memes/281ba8a8dc6c7121ab4a24c8306c9481.jpg" alt=""/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```
.video-item-programs {
  position: relative;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.video-item-programs__play::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 14.5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 24px solid #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 14.5px solid transparent;
}
.video-item-programs__play::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  border: 1px solid #dcca87;
  background: transparent;
}

.isPlaying .video-item-programs__play {
  display: none;
}

.video-item-programs__item {
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  object-fit: cover;
  background-color: #f3e1e9;
  cursor: pointer;
}
img{
  width: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`transform:translate(50%,50%)`

**не является корректным выравниванием,
лучше используйте**

```
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
```

для постановки любого элемента по центру какой то условной рамки советую сделайть так:

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

`display: flex` заставляет использовать флексбоксы для родительского(их) элементов

`justify-content: center` заставляет элемент(ы) встать по середине горизонтал

`align-items: center` аналогично по вертикали

`width` и `height` можно указать определенные, а можно указать их значение `inherit`, тогда они возьмут ширину и длину у родительского элемента

> непосредственно флексбоксы можно использовать не только для div`а но и для любых других блочных элементов

также советую поучиться использовать flexbox`ы на основе [игры](https://flexboxfroggy.com/#ru)